# How can I get the value from a cell in other workbooks based on dynamic file path

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, filenames

I would like to get the cell value from other workbooks to my master file.

Those files are in the same folder `G:\Data\xxx\yyy` while the file name is customer ID.

I.e. the file path could be `G:\Data\xxx\yyy\123` or `G:\Data\xxx\yyy\234`
And the value I would like to extract from those workbooks is in `Sheet ABC` cell `J55`.

So the formula I input in the cell is = `G:\Data\xxx\yyy [123.xlsm]'!$J$55`

In the master file, I have a list of customer ID in Column A and I would like to get the value from cell J55 in other workbooks. i.e. create a dynamic file path to get the numbers and paste it to column B.

However, I tried to combine the link with the “CONCATENATE” and “G” but didn’t work out.

I tried the indirect function but it requires me to open the referencing workbooks that is not ideal.

Is that a way for me to get the numbers?

VBA coding is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that can be run from Excel VBA. I admit it might be overkill to solving your issue but it will check column A for values and fill column B if it is blank from J55 of the selected workbooks without opening any of them. 
It assumes you have Microsoft Access as part of your office suite, are running on a 64 bit version of Windows, the files your are retrieving data from have a .xlsx extension and the data you want from J55 is on "Sheet1". If any of these assumptions are incorrect please let me know as the code can be easily adjust to accommodate.

From the information you have provided it seems that the file path for all the files you would like to access are static (G:\Data\xxx\yyy) and only the file name is dynamic (file name = Customer ID # from column A). You will need to make a reference to Microsoft XML v6.0 and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library.

The code below is mostly cut and pasted from another project I wrote. It does still need to be tested. I would advise adding some error handling and the normal performance enhancing vba code like turning off screen updating.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    'Folder where Wb live
    Const FilePath As String = "G:\Data\xxx\yyy\"

    'Command string
    Const request_SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

    'Get last row
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Create Array from Main worksheet
    Dim MainWsArray As Variant
    MainWsArray = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 2))


    Dim FullFileName As String

    'Create a connection to be used throughout the loop
    Dim Cnx As ADODB.Connection
    Set Cnx = New ADODB.Connection

    Dim CustomerId As Long
    Dim RowCounter As Long
    Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Set Rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    'Loop through Array to get values
    For RowCounter = 1 To LastRow
        If MainWsArray(2, RowCounter) = vbNullString Then
            CustomerId = MainWsArray(1, RowCounter).Value
            FullFileName = FilePath & CustomerId
            AssignCnx Cnx, FullFileName

            'Create RecordSet

            If OpenRecordset(Rst, request_SQL, Cnx) Then
                MsgBox "Unable to open Recordset. " & CustomerId
            End If

            'Use recordset to get data from file.
            Rst.Move 54
            MainWsArray(2, RowCounter) = Rst.Fields(10)
        End If
        Rst.Close
        Cnx.Close
    Next RowCounter

    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2)) = MainWsArray()

    If Not Rst Is Nothing Then Set Rst = Nothing
    If Not Cnx Is Nothing Then Set Cnx = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub AssignCnx(ByRef Cnx As ADODB.Connection, ByVal FullFileName As String)

    'Connection
    With Cnx
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" 'or "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for 32bit
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & FullFileName & _
           ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;Readonly=False'"
        .Open
    End With

End Sub

Private Function OpenRecordset(ByRef Rst As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal request_SQL As String, ByRef Cnx As ADODB.Connection) As Boolean
    'Error Trapping for the RecordSet

    Dim backupRequestString As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Rst.Open request_SQL, Cnx, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        OpenRecordset = False
        Exit Function
    Else
        Rst.Close
        OpenRecordset = True
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

I hope you find this helpful. If it is a bit much there are other ways to link workbooks to the master file from within Excel w/o VBA. It's been a long time since I have done it that way though. Best of luck.